# Flipping a Drawn Image

Tags: c#, winforms, draw, game-physics

I'm making a little C# project which requires me to move an image that has already been drawn into the form. Here is the drawing algorithm:

```
public void DrawImagePoint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Create image.
    newImage = A_Worm_Nightmare.Properties.Resources.Worm;
    // Create Point for upper-left corner of image.
    Point ulCorner = new Point(50, 50);
    // Draw image to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, ulCorner);
}
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawImagePoint(e);
}
```

Question: How do you flip an already drawn object in WinForms, since implementing this method in a timer is not possible? (`timer_Tick` does not support `PaintEventArgs`) The fliping is by `Cursor.Position.X`. Here is the algorithm for a normal `Picturebox":

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool Ok = true;

    if (Cursor.Position.X <= 135 && Ok)
    {
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
        Ok = false;
    }
    else if (Cursor.Position.X >= 135 && !Ok)
    {
        Ok = true;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Initially your question was to move it, and now it seem you changed it to flip? what's the actual question? Which part is not working?

Comment: Fliping it is the objective, the movement thing was another question which I managed to find an answer to. I apologise for the confusion. So the question is : how do you flip it once it is drawn.

Comment: I undeleted my answer again, see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need a timer. Just change the location in Timer's Tick and call `Invalidate`, it will make your form to repaint.

```
private Point location = Point.Empty;
private Image newImage;
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    location.Offset(1,1);
    //Do flipping here
    newImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
    this.Invalidate();//Makes form to repaint
}

public void DrawImagePoint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if(newImage == null)
    {
        newImage = A_Worm_Nightmare.Properties.Resources.Worm;    
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, location);
}
```

You can setup a timer with whatever frequency, and that should work.

also note that `Resources.Image` will create new `Image` every time you query it. So you should cache the image somewhere to avoid that overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do.
You must Call

```
this.Refresh();
```

on the timer event.
this will trigger the paint event.

Comment: "this" referring to the form.